# NLP for Sign Language

Tags: nlp, recurrent-neural-network, gesture-recognition, mediapipe, sequence-to-sequence

I have successfully developed an ML model that effectively recognizes American Sign Language using the pre-trained "Gesture Recognizer" model from MediaPipe (https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/gesture_recognizer).

However, I am now faced with the challenge of ensuring grammatical accuracy when translating sign language into English sentences. Not all English words have direct equivalents in American Sign Language, such as the absence of a sign for the word "Are". My objective is to create a mobile application that can accurately recognize complete sentences based on sign language inputs. For instance, if a deaf person signs "Hello, How, You," the application should generate the complete sentence "Hello, How are you." To achieve this, I am seeking guidance on developing an NLP model that can complement the sign predictions and add the necessary words to form grammatically correct sentences. Any insights or suggestions regarding this endeavor would be greatly appreciated.